# spring.datasource.platform is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I made a project from scratch just with the `schema.sql` and the `data.sql` just to try the `schema.sql` and the `data.sql`:

- https://github.com/rmmcosta/TestSchema
  Everything works fine. The table inside `schema.sql` is created in a `MySQL` database (previously created and the grants were given to the user defined in the `application.properties` file) and the `data.sql` populates the data as it's supposed to do.

But, when I change `schema.sql` and `data.sql` to `schema-mysql.sql` and `data-mysql.sql` and I put in the `application.properties` the property `spring.datasource.platform=mysql` then the `schema-mysql.sql` and `data-mysql.sql` scripts files are **not** executed.

No errors are being thrown, simple nothing happens on the database.
I tried with `Spring Boot` **2.2.4** and it works fine, but with `Spring Boot` **2.7.5** it isn't working.

Do you know if the `spring.datasource.platform` was deprecated? And if so, do you know how can I set the `application.properties` in order to run `schema-mysql.sql`?

Thank you in advance,
Ricardo

Note:
I tried without using `spring.datasource.platform=mysql` and with `schema.sql` and `data.sql` and everything works fine.
I tried with an old project, Spring Boot 2.2.4 and Java 1.8, and works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you know if the spring.datasource.platform was deprecated? And if so, do you know how can I set the application.properties in order to run schema-mysql.sql?

The property name changed to `spring.sql.init.platform`

GitHub [additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d870474fcd4899fac94d51311c4163832d6b109d/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json#L1148) file - line 1148

Which occurred in Spring Boot 2.5: [Spring Boot 2.5.0 RC1 Configuration Changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5.0-RC1-Configuration-Changelog)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use spring.sql.init.platform instead of spring.datasource.platform property in application.properties.

Please see the comment from latest documentation -

> In addition, Spring Boot processes the schema-${platform}.sql and
> data-${platform}.sql files (if present), where platform is the value
> of spring.sql.init.platform